# Why are my variables highlighted in blue?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a dataframe called `propertydf`.

When I run my code I get a very vague error:

```
propertydf = propertydf[propertydf['fixed_price'].notna()].copy()
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I checked the code and the dataframe variable has changed color to blue? But not all of them.

I also noticed some other variables are suddenly blue, such as `year` and `date`.

I think this is causing the error.  How can I fix it?

[image]

Comment: Count the number of parentheses on the line before the error

Comment: You're missing a bracket

Comment: d'oh. I am obviously a noob. Thanks folks

Comment: @Adam.Er8: We wouldn't be able to see the syntax highlighting if they posted text, though. I think this is a reasonable case for a screenshot.

Comment: @Adam.Er8 I wanted to show the colors. I thought that was the problem. I'm still learning vscode.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I agree, reversing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the line `propertydf['fixed_price'] = fix_price((propertydf.iloc[:,[4]])` you open two parenthesis but only close one (It's above the line that throws the error).